# Is there a way to combine a list like this?

Tags: python, list

assume that a and b are list.

```py
a = [[1], [2]]   
b = [[5, 6, 7], [3, 4, 5]]
```

I want to get a list which is

```
[[1,5,6,7], [2,3,4,5]]
```

Is there any way to do that effectively? Either lists or numpy array is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zip` is your friend:

```
>>> a = [[1], [2]]
>>> b = [[5, 6, 7], [3, 4, 5]]
>>> [x+y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
[[1, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

You can also use `map`; the `operator` module provides a ready-made definition of `lambda x,y: x + y` for such uses.

```
>>> import operator
>>> list(map(operator.add, a, b))
```